# Simpler / faster / more elegant way to split a string at custom positions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been searching for a simpler way to do this, but i'm not sure what search parameters to use. I have a floating point number, that i would like to round, convert to a string, then specify a custom format on the string. I've read through the .format docs, but can't see if it's possible to do this using normal string formatting.

The output i want is just a normal string, with spaces every three chars, except for the last ones, which should have a space four chars before the end.

For example, i made this convoluted function that does what i want in an inefficient way:

```
def my_formatter(value):
    final = []
    # round float and convert to list of strings of individual chars
    c = [i for i in '{:.0f}'.format(value)]
    if len(c) > 3:
        final.append(''.join(c[-4:]))
        c = c[:-4]
    else:
        return ''.join(c)
    for i in range(0, len(c) // 3 + 1, 1):
        if len(c) > 2:
            final.insert(0, ''.join(c[-3:]))
            c = c[:-3]
        elif len(c) > 0:
            final.insert(0, ''.join(c))
    return(' '.join(final))
```

e.g.

```
>>> my_formatter(123456789.12)
>>> '12 345 6789'
>>> my_formatter(12345678912.34)
>>> '1 234 567 8912'
```

Would really appreciate guidance on doing this in a simpler / more efficient way.

Comment: What's the format of the string you want as an output?

Comment: Just want a normal string, with spaces every three chars, except for the last ones, which should have a space four chars before the end.

Comment: Please add that in the question itself.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar Question updated to reflect expected output, tx.

Comment: Are you trying to do this to match Indian-style monetary/large-number grouping? If so, there's a recent discussion on either python-ideas or python-dev to add either that, or a more general way to specify digit groupings that would be able to handle that, to Python 3.7 or 3.8. I don't know the status of the proposal, and obviously you can't just wait around for 3.8 and hope the feature is there, but… I'll bet the discussion had multiple people saying "This is unnecessary, because any idiot could just write this trivial code" (followed by code  that does exactly what you want).

Comment: @abarnert Good pointer, thanks for mentioning! It's not for Indian-style large number counting specifically, but the concept is exactly the same, format a number into custom groupings.

Comment: @abarnert, if possible, can you share the link? Don't bother if you've to search it.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar It'll be in the [python-ideas archive](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/). If you prefer searching via NNTP or one of the nicer third-party archives, I think you can find info about them somewhere in the Community section, maybe [here](https://www.python.org/community/lists/). The discussion started somewhere around December and January, and the thread title was… I think the Hindi work for 10000 or something like that, but I don't remember for sure.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar Anyway, from what I remember (which may be way off), India traditionally uses different grouping than Europe both for money and for large numbers, and one of the two is a 2-2-2-…-4 grouping. I didn't read the whole thread; I'm just guessing this is the kind of thing one of the core devs would think is trivial, and then rattle off some code off the top of his head that would have taken me days to get that nice.

Comment: @abarnert Yes, you are correct. But it's not 2-2-2...-4, it's 2-2-2-...-3.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar Oops; thanks. Anyway, any code that did 2-2-2-…-3 could be adapted pretty quickly to 2-2-2-…-4. Also, I found [the initial post](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2018-January/048796.html), and you can click Next By Thread from there.

Comment: Now that I think about it, US phone numbers are basically ∞-3-3-4, which could benefit from the exact code for this question…

Answer (score 3):

Took a slightly different angle but this uses a third party function [`partition_all`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.partition_all). In short, I use it to group the string into groups of 3 plus the final group if there are less than 3 chars. You may prefer this as there are no for loops or conditionals but it's basically cosmetic differences.

```
from toolz.itertoolz import partition_all
def simpleformat(x):
    x = str(round(x))
    a, b = x[:-4], x[-4:]
    strings = [''.join(x[::-1]) for x in reversed(list(partition_all(3, a[::-1])))]
    return ' '.join(strings + [b])
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
def my_formatter(x):
    # round it as text
    txt = "{:.0f}".format(x)

    # find split indices
    splits = [None] + list(range(-4, -len(txt), -3)) + [None]

    # slice and rejoin
    return " ".join(
        reversed([txt[i:j] for i, j in zip(splits[1:], splits[:-1])]))
```

Then

```
>>> my_formatter(123456789.1)
12 345 6789
>>> my_formatter(1123456789.1)
112 345 6789
>>> my_formatter(11123456789.1)
1 112 345 6789
```

Comment: Nice; doing the backward range and one reverse instead of two reverses.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pretty simple solution using a loop over the elements in the reverse order such that counting the indices is easier:

```
num = 12345678912.34

temp = []
for ix, c in enumerate(reversed(str(round(num)))):
    if ix%3 == 0 and ix !=0: temp.extend([c, ' '])
    else: temp.extend(c)

''.join(list(reversed(temp)))
```

Output:

> '1 234 567 8912'

Using list comprehensions we can do this in a single very confusing line as

```
num = 12345678912.34

''.join(list(reversed(list(''.join([c+' ' if(ix%3 == 0 and ix!=0) else c for ix, c in enumerate(reversed(str(round(num))))])))))
```

> '1 234 567 8912'

Comment: I'll simplify it with list comprehensions.

Comment: `if ix==3 and ix%3==0`? If the first part is true, the second part is automatically true as well.

Comment: Also, you might want make temp a list of strings so you can just `temp.append` each time and then `''.join(temp)` at the end, to avoid all the string concatenation. Not really any more complicated, and more idiomatic, and a lot more efficient for older versions of Python.

Comment: @JahKnows Nice approach, thanks for sharing! Note that for 1234567890 it appends a space at the front, but in my current state i've got a good mind to just .strip() the return value.

Comment: @abarnert, I tried your suggestion regarding the `x==3` and `x%3` however it is necessary, because we only want to do the first grouping of 4 for the first group. Note that `ix=3` is the 4th character.

Comment: @abarnert, I chnaged the way I approached the logic, I think for readability this way of writing it would be better.

Comment: @JahKnows You needed the ix%3 on the other line, but not the ix==3 line. But at any rate, it doesn't matter; the new version doesn't have that code, and is even better. Too bad I can't upvote it again. :) I still think it would be better to make temp a list of strings that you join up at the end, though.

Answer (score 2):

Another approch is to use locale if available on your system of course, and use format.

```
import locale

for v in ('fr_FR.UTF-8', 'en_GB.UTF-8'):
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, v)
    print(v, '>> {:n}'.format(111222333999))
```

Answer (score 1):

May as well share another slightly different variant, but still can't shake the feeling that there's some sublime way that we just can't see. Haven't marked any answers as correct yet, because i'm convinced python can do this in a simpler way, somehow. What's also driving me crazy is that if i remember correctly VB's format command can handle this (with a pattern like "### ####0"). Maybe it's just a case of not understanding how to use Python's .format correctly.

The below accepts a float or decimal and a list indicating split positions. If there are still digits in the string after consuming the last split position, it re-applies that until it reaches the start of the string.

```
def format_number(num, pat, sep=' '):
    fmt = []
    strn = "{:.0f}".format(num)
    while strn:
        p = pat.pop() if pat else p
        fmt.append(strn[-p:])
        strn = strn[:-p] if len(strn) > p else ''
    return sep.join(fmt[::-1])

>>> format_number(123456789, [3, 4])
>>> '12 345 6789'
>>> format_number(1234567890, [3])
>>> '1 234 567 890'
```